# Loading Javascript in Flash (picture reference)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I need help! i want to load a picture url in Flash AS3 i have the following code in javascript that shows the picture. however i want to load the same reference in Flash..

```
FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) { 
function detect(URL) {
       var image = new Image();
       image.src = URL;
       image.onload = function() {
       var result = 'result'; // An example result
    }
document.body.appendChild(image)
}
detect("https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username + "/picture?width=200&height=200");
```

Comment: And ..what does this have to do with Java?  'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call the API from AS3 directly because Facebook's library is written in JavaScript. You'll have to use JS as the intermediary. However, Gio's response above is correct. Use the ExternalInterface API to pass a message from JS to AS. I'm pasting the modifications you need to make in JS below which builds upon what he has written.

His answer is correct and complete and you should mark it as such.

```
FB.api('/me?fields=username', function(response) { 
function detect(URL) {
       var image = new Image();
       image.src = URL;
       image.onload = function() {
       var result = 'result'; // An example result
    }

// Pasted from Gio's code above
var swf = document.getElementById("myFlash"); // get a reference
swf.loadImage(myURL); // call your AS3 function
}
detect("https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.username + "/picture?width=200&height=200");
```

Comment: well it does not work, i need to load the picture in Flash AS3 with the use of the javascript reference. ..

Answer (score 1):

You load images in Actionscript 3 using `Loader` class:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

function loadImage(url:String):void
{
    var l:Loader = new Loader();
    var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

    l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
    l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);
    l.load(r);

    function onLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("Couldn't load image.");
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);
    }

    function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("Load completed!");
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);

        stage.addChild(e.target.content); // e.target.content holds the loaded bitmap
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can listen for a call from Javascipt using a callback and `ExternalInterface`:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available) // check that SWF is running in a browser
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("loadImage", loadImage);
```

Then you call the function from Javascript using a reference to the SWF. For example if your Flash is embedded like this:

```
<embed src="flash.swf" id="myFlash" width="800" height="600" />
```

You can get a reference to it using the `document.getElementById()` method in Javascript:

```
var swf = document.getElementById("myFlash"); // get a reference
swf.loadImage(myURL); // call your AS3 function
```

**UPDATE 1**

I made this simple example for you to try out and to understand what I was telling you: [Download Example](http://db.tt/5VCXLOX6)

Please note that this will only work in Firefox, because I embedded it using the embed tag which is having problems with Chrome, but if you embed it correctly it works cross-browser.

Comment: Hi the thing is i need to load in the javascript reference. in this case the url because this is just a small part of the java script. the javasript gets random ID'd form friends form facebook. so i neeed to load the picture with the use of that function

Comment: You can call an Actionscript function from the Javascript and pass in the url as a parameter. I'll update my answer

Comment: The example I provided does that exactly. Please read more carefully.

Comment: now it loads the link from flash to java,,, i need to have it the other way around

Comment: @BasMienis wait I'll upload an example for you.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the link to the example. I've also included a CS5 FLA in case you have older Flash Pro. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, that is not working for me.... i am using chrome.. however it should work in safari and it does not